# Why am I getting "Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object" error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is the code for my private server realmeye http://www.thenoxusproject.org/realmeye/index.php 
And I keep receiving this error, and I do not know how to fix it, please help?

> Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/noxus/public_html/realmeye/index.php on line 112

===============================================================

index.php code is below

```
<?php 

require_once('template/config.php');
// database info
define('HOST','MY VPS IP');
define('DB','rotmg');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','DB PASSWORD');
function connect_db()
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB,USER,PASS);
    return $db;
}
?>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, target-densityDpi=device-dpi">
    <title>Player List</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="msapplication-config" content="none">
    <link rel="canonical" href="/top-players-by-fame">
    <meta name="keywords" content="realm of the mad god, rotmg, statistics, stats,top players,by fame">
    <meta name="description" content="Top Players in Realm of the Mad God by fame 1-101.">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/typeahead.js-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/tablesorter.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/realmeye.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style id="swaggy">
        #plscenterme {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
<?php require_once('template/navbar.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="plscenterme">
                <h1><?= SERVER_NAME . ' - Player list' ?></h1>
                <p>Noxus Player List</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="text-center">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li <?= $type == 'all' ? "class='active'" : '' ?>><a href="index.php?type=all">All</a></li>

            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <style type="text/css">
                #c th:nth-child(1), #c td:nth-child(1), #c th:nth-child(4), #c td:nth-child(4), #c th:nth-child(5), #c td:nth-child(5), #c th:nth-child(6), #c td:nth-child(6), #c th:nth-child(7), #c td:nth-child(7), #c th:nth-child(8), #c td:nth-child(8), #c th:nth-child(9), #c td:nth-child(9) {
                    text-align: right
                }
            </style>
            <table id="c" class="table table-striped tablesorter">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="header"></th>
                    <th class="header">Name</th>
                    <th class="header">Guild</th>
                    <th class="header">Fame</th>
                    <th class="header">Exp</th>
                    <th class="header">
                        <abbr title="Rank">R</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th class="header">
                        <abbr title="Chars">C</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th class="header">
                        <abbr title="Avg. Fame / Char">AF/C</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th class="header">
                        <abbr title="Avg. Exp / Char">AE/C</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th class="header">Last seen</th>
                    <th class="header">
                        <abbr title="Server">Srv.</abbr>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
        $count = 1;
                $accounts = $type == 'all' ? get_accounts() : get_accounts();
                while ($row = $accounts->fetch_assoc())
                { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Number -->
                        <td><?=$count . '.' ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="star-container">
                                <!-- Name -->
                                <a href="player.php?player=<?=$row['name'] ?>"><?=$row['name'] ?></a>
                                <!-- Rank/Stars -->
                                <div class="star star-white"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <!-- Guild -->
                        <td><?php
                            $currentGuildID = $row1['guild'];
                            $guildName = "";
                            $table = "SELECT * FROM 'guilds' WHERE 'id'=$currentGuildID";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die ('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row1 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $guildName = $row1['name'];
                            }
                            if ($currentGuildID == 0)
                                echo "None";
                            echo $guildName;
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- Fame/FameHistory-->
                        <td><?php
                            $currentFame = "";
                            $accId = get_id_from_name($row['name'])->fetch_assoc()['id'];
                            $table = "SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `accId`=$accId and dead=0";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row2 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $currentFame = $currentFame + $row2['fame'];
                            }

                            if ($currentFame == 0 or $currentFame == null) {
                                echo "0";
                            }else {
                                echo $currentFame;}
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- EXP -->
                        <td><?php
                            $currentEXP = "";
                            $accId = get_id_from_name($row['name'])->fetch_assoc()['id'];
                            $table = "SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `accId`=$accId and dead=0";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row3 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $currentEXP = $currentEXP + $row3['exp'];
                            }
                            if ($currentEXP == 0 or $currentEXP == null) {
                                echo "0";
                            }else {
                            echo $currentEXP;}
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- Rank -->
                        <td><?php
                            $currentRank = "";
                            $accId = get_id_from_name($row['name']) -> fetch_assoc()['id'];
                            $table = "SELECT `rank` FROM `accounts` WHERE `id`=$accId";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row4 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $currentRank += $row4['rank'];
                            }
                            echo $currentRank;
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- Characters -->
                        <td><?php
                            $charamount = 0;
                            $accId = get_id_from_name($row['name'])->fetch_assoc()['id'];
                            $table = "select * from characters where accId=$accId and dead=0";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row5 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $charamount++;
                            }
                            echo $charamount;
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- Average Fame/Char -->
                        <td><?php
                            $allFameAddedUp = 0;
                            $charCount = 0;
                $accId = get_id_from_name($row['name'])->fetch_assoc()['id'];
                            $table = "select * from characters where accId=$accId and dead=0";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row6 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $allFameAddedUp += $row6['fame'];
                                $charCount++;
                            }
                            if ($allFameAddedUp == 0) {
                                echo "0";
                            }else {
                            echo $allFameAddedUp / $charCount;
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- Average EXP/Char -->
                        <td><?php
                            $allEXPAddedUp = 0;
                            $charCount1 = 0;
                $accId = get_id_from_name($row['name'])->fetch_assoc()['id'];
                            $table = "select * from characters where accId=$accId and dead=0";
                            $query = $pdo->query($table) or die('An error occurred.');
                            while ($row7 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
                            {
                                $allEXPAddedUp += $row7['exp'];
                                $charCount1++;
                            }
                            if ($allEXPAddedUp == 0) {
                                echo "0";
                            }else {
                                echo $allEXPAddedUp / $charCount1;
                            }
                            ?></td>
                        <!-- Last seen-->
                        <td>
                            <abbr title="<?= SERVER_NAME ?>">
                                FSOD
                            </abbr>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php $count++; } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.timeago.en-short.js"></script>
<script src="js/definition.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script src="js/realmeye.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
            initializeSearch("a");
        }
    );
    initializeClickHandlerWithAction("b", {
            "type": "POST",
            "url": "\/logout",
            "data": {}
        }
    );
    makeSortable("c", {
            0: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            1: {
                "sorter": "text"
            }
            ,
            2: {
                "sorter": "text"
            }
            ,
            3: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            4: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            5: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            6: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            7: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            8: {
                "sorter": "digit"
            }
            ,
            9: {
                "sorter": "text"
            }
            ,
            10: {
                "sorter": "text"
            }
        }
    );
    renderNumeric("c", 1);
    renderNumeric("c", 4);
    renderNumeric("c", 5);
    renderNumeric("c", 6);
    renderNumeric("c", 7);
    renderNumeric("c", 8);
    renderNumeric("c", 9);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(["_setAccount", "UA-36039145-1"]);
    _gaq.push(["_setSiteSpeedSampleRate", 10]);
    _gaq.push(["_setSampleRate", "80"]);
    _gaq.push(["_gat._anonymizeIp"]);
    _gaq.push(["_setCustomVar", 1, "ssl", /^https/.test(window.location.href) ? "yes" : "no"]);
    _gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);

    (function () {
        var ga = document.createElement("script");
        ga.type = "text/javascript";
        ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource (or mysqli\_result), boolean given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-or-mysqli-result-boole). There are numerous possible duplicates to this question.

Comment: There is no object reference on line 112. There would be a bigger chance to give an answer if you would highlight the line in quest. However, looks like your database connection does not succeed.

Comment: You never call `connect_db()`.

Comment: @Barmar so I would put "connect_db()" below function connect_db()?

Answer (score 7):

If you notice, 1) you have no `connect_db()` in your script and 2) your function is creating `$pdo` yet returning `$db` so even if you use `connect_db()` it would return nothing:

```
function connect_db()
{
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DB,USER,PASS);
    // You need to return $pdo not $db
    return $pdo;
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Because you may or may not be using the connection throughout your page, you may want to create your function at the top and feed it into any functions you are using, specifically this part: `$accounts = $type == 'all' ? get_accounts() : get_accounts();`

This ternary doesn't make any sense, by the way, you are assigning the function on `true` or `false` either way:

```
// You are saying if 'all', use 'get_accounts()' but if not 'all' use it 'get_accounts()' as well...
$accounts = $type == 'all' ? get_accounts() : get_accounts();
```

To fix, just do:

```
$con = connect_db();
$accounts = get_accounts($con);
```

I noticed you are using `$pdo` down the page so, you may want to change to `$pdo` instead:

```
$pdo = connect_db();
$accounts = get_accounts($pdo);
```

Comment: So what would I do to fix this?

Comment: Use the function I revised and assign the connection to a variable like `$con=connect_db();`

Comment: then you can use it like `$query = $con->prepare("select whatever from wherever"); $query->execute();`

Comment: Presumably you are using the connection in the `get_accounts()` function?

Comment: Wait what? where is the connection variable?

Comment: In your case where ever your `get_accounts()` is, the connection would be in there.

Comment: Better would be to assign the connection at the top of the page and feed it as an argument into the function like `get_accounts($con)`

Comment: I know receive this http://i.imgur.com/TOG9BQE.png @Rasclatt

Comment: You need to first test that your connection is working. Can you do a simple select statement?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do :

```
$pdo = connect_db()
```

before you can use the `$pdo` variable.

You also need to fix `connect_db()` so it returns the same variable that it assigned.

Comment: So the code for this would be?
Sorry I've spent a lot of work on this and I'm just over worked and confused atm.

Comment: `$accounts = $type == 'all' ? get_accounts() : get_accounts(); while ($row = $accounts->fetch_assoc())` but getaccounts() (which should return a result handle) is not included in the code.

Comment: @OrganizedChaos Change `return $pdo` to `return $db`

Answer (score 1):

`connect_db()` is never called, so your $pdo variable is left uninitiallized. When you first call `$pdo->query()`, PHP complains $pdo is not an object.